# Why Simple Oracle Update Statement Make Block Session?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, query-optimization, oracle19c

I have simple Oracle (19C) update statement like this and it is making block sessions some times. This update query is running from an ASP.NET MVC System which uses Entity Framework. Since I am new to this issue, Can anyone provide me an idea how I can figure out the exact issue, what can be the reason and how can I resolve it?

```
UPDATE "TICKET_TRACKINGPRD"."TKT_TICKET"
SET
    "TITLE" = :b22,
    "SUMMARY" = :b21,
    "DESCRIPTION" = :b20,
    "ENVIRONMENT" = :b19,
    "TICKET_PROJECT_ID" = :b18,
    "TICKET_PROJECT_MODULE_ID" = NULL,
    "APPLICATION_TYPE_ID" = :b17,
    "APPLICATION_ID" = :b16,
    "APPLICATION_MODULE_ID" = :b15,
    "APPLICATION_SERVICE_ID" = :b14,
    "SERVICE_CHANNEL_ID" = :b13,
    "TICKET_STATUS_ID" = :b12,
    "TICKET_RESOLUTION_ID" = :b11,
    "TICKET_PRIORITY_ID" = :b10,
    "ASSIGNEE_ID" = :b9,
    "DUE_DATE" = :b8,
    "REPORTED_BY_USER_NAME" = :b7,
    "USER_LANGUAGE_ID" = :b6,
    "CLOSED_DATE" = NULL,
    "CLOSED_BY_USER_ID" = NULL,
    "CONTEXT_KEY" = NULL,
    "CONTEXT_URL" = NULL,
    "CREATED_DATE" = :b5,
    "MODIFIED_DATE" = :b4,
    "CREATED_BY_USER_ID" = :b3,
    "MODIFIED_BY_USER_ID" = :b2,
    "RECORD_STATUS_ID" = :b1
WHERE
    ("ID" = :b23)
RETURNING "KEY" INTO : o0
```

[image]

Comment: Is ID a primary key?

Comment: @APC yes ID is the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying that this **is** "it", but ... might be.

> what can be the reason

Looks like the *unindexed foreign keys* issue. Basically, all foreign key columns should be indexed. As [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/data-integrity.html#GUID-8D485547-5304-4FE7-A1B3-8A4009484A6A) says:

> Indexing the foreign keys in child tables provides the following benefits:
>
> - Prevents a full table lock on the child table. Instead, the database acquires a row lock on the index.

For more info, read [Locks and foreign keys](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/data-concurrency-and-consistency.html#GUID-261F98F8-F7B4-49A9-9BE8-11F2B1F4609B).

---

> and how can I resolve it?

Obviously, by indexing foreign key columns. But, first you have to find them. I use Tom Kyte's script (adjusted a little bit):

```
/* 12.12.2012. Tom Kyte: locating unindexed foreign keys

   14.03.2016. PAR_WHAT: 0    - show those that aren't OK
                         1    - show those that are OK
                         NULL - show all
*/

WITH forkey
     AS (SELECT DECODE (b.table_name, NULL, '****', 'ok') Status,
                a.table_name,
                a.columns column_1,
                b.columns column_2
           FROM (  SELECT SUBSTR (a.table_name, 1, 30) table_name,
                          SUBSTR (a.constraint_name, 1, 30) constraint_name,
                             MAX (
                                DECODE (position,
                                        1, SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                        NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (position,
                                        2, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                        NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (position,
                                        3, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                        NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (position,
                                        4, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                        NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (position,
                                        5, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                        NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (position,
                                        6, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                        NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (position,
                                        7, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                        NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (position,
                                        8, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                        NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (position,
                                        9, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                        NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (
                                   position,
                                   10, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                   NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (
                                   position,
                                   11, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                   NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (
                                   position,
                                   12, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                   NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (
                                   position,
                                   13, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                   NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (
                                   position,
                                   14, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                   NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (
                                   position,
                                   15, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                   NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (
                                   position,
                                   16, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                   NULL))
                             columns
                     FROM user_cons_columns a, user_constraints b
                    WHERE     a.constraint_name = b.constraint_name
                          AND b.constraint_type = 'R'
                 GROUP BY SUBSTR (a.table_name, 1, 30),
                          SUBSTR (a.constraint_name, 1, 30)) a,
                (  SELECT SUBSTR (table_name, 1, 30) table_name,
                          SUBSTR (index_name, 1, 30) index_name,
                             MAX (
                                DECODE (column_position,
                                        1, SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                        NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (column_position,
                                        2, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                        NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (column_position,
                                        3, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                        NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (column_position,
                                        4, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                        NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (column_position,
                                        5, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                        NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (column_position,
                                        6, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                        NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (column_position,
                                        7, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                        NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (column_position,
                                        8, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                        NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (column_position,
                                        9, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                        NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (
                                   column_position,
                                   10, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                   NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (
                                   column_position,
                                   11, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                   NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (
                                   column_position,
                                   12, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                   NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (
                                   column_position,
                                   13, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                   NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (
                                   column_position,
                                   14, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                   NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (
                                   column_position,
                                   15, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                   NULL))
                          || MAX (
                                DECODE (
                                   column_position,
                                   16, ', ' || SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 30),
                                   NULL))
                             columns
                     FROM user_ind_columns
                 GROUP BY SUBSTR (table_name, 1, 30),
                          SUBSTR (index_name, 1, 30)) b
          WHERE     a.table_name = b.table_name(+)
                AND b.columns(+) LIKE a.columns || '%'
                AND a.table_name NOT LIKE 'HEP_DP%')
  SELECT f.status,
         f.table_name,
         f.column_1,
         f.column_2
    FROM forkey f
   WHERE f.status =
            CASE
               WHEN :par_what = 1 THEN 'ok'
               WHEN :par_what = 0 THEN '****'
               ELSE f.status
            END
ORDER BY f.table_name, f.column_1, f.column_2
/
```

For example:

```
SQL> create table a (id number primary key);

Table created.

SQL> create table b (id number constraint fk_ba references a (id));

Table created.
```

Table `B` misses index on its foreign key constraint column, so query returns:

```
SQL> /

STATUS     TABLE_NAME COLUMN_1   COLUMN_2
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
****       B          ID
```

Create an index:

```
SQL> create index a1bid on b (id);

Index created.
```

Query doesn't return anything now:

```
SQL> /

no rows selected
```

See if it helps.